# Can't bind to 'filter' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

we're using (hoping to be able to use) Angular 4 with the full service Kendo Grid (filter, sorting, paging etc). The simple grid works as well as pagination but when I try to add filtering I get the following:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'filter' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'.
1. If 'kendo-grid' is an Angular component and it has 'filter' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-grid' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("      [pageSize]="state.take"
                        [skip]="state.skip"
                        [ERROR ->][filter]="state.filter"
                        [pageable]="true"
                        [filterab"): ng:///app/securityGroupComponent.html@26:24
Can't bind to 'filterable' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'...
```

I can't identify what is different between my set-up and the docs. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { process, State } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

import {
    GridComponent,
    GridDataResult,
    DataStateChangeEvent
} from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
<kendo-grid
        [data]="gridData"
        [pageSize]="state.take"
        [skip]="state.skip"
        [sort]="state.sort"
        [filter]="state.filter"
        [sortable]="true"
        [pageable]="true"
        [filterable]="true"
        (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
    >
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40" [filterable]="false">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="FirstOrderedOn" title="First Ordered On" width="240" filter="date" format="{0:d}">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" width="180" filter="numeric" format="{0:c}">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" width="120" filter="boolean">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled/>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
`
})
export class test {

    private state: State = {
        skip: 0,
        take: 5
    };
    private sampleProducts = [
        {
            "ProductID": 1,
            "ProductName": "Chai",
            "SupplierID": 1,
            "CategoryID": 1,
            "QuantityPerUnit": "10 boxes x 20 bags",
            "UnitPrice": 18,
            "UnitsInStock": 39,
            "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
            "ReorderLevel": 10,
            "Discontinued": false,
            "Category": {
                "CategoryID": 1,
                "CategoryName": "Beverages",
                "Description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
            },
            "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 8, 20)
        },
        {
            "ProductID": 2,
            "ProductName": "Chang",
            "SupplierID": 1,
            "CategoryID": 1,
            "QuantityPerUnit": "24 - 12 oz bottles",
            "UnitPrice": 19,
            "UnitsInStock": 17,
            "UnitsOnOrder": 40,
            "ReorderLevel": 25,
            "Discontinued": false,
            "Category": {
                "CategoryID": 1,
                "CategoryName": "Beverages",
                "Description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
            },
            "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 7, 12)
        },
        {
            "ProductID": 3,
            "ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup",
            "SupplierID": 1,
            "CategoryID": 2,
            "QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles",
            "UnitPrice": 10,
            "UnitsInStock": 13,
            "UnitsOnOrder": 70,
            "ReorderLevel": 25,
            "Discontinued": false,
            "Category": {
                "CategoryID": 2,
                "CategoryName": "Condiments",
                "Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
            },
            "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 8, 26)
        },
        {
            "ProductID": 4,
            "ProductName": "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",
            "SupplierID": 2,
            "CategoryID": 2,
            "QuantityPerUnit": "48 - 6 oz jars",
            "UnitPrice": 22,
            "UnitsInStock": 53,
            "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
            "ReorderLevel": 0,
            "Discontinued": false,
            "Category": {
                "CategoryID": 2,
                "CategoryName": "Condiments",
                "Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
            },
            "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 9, 19)
        },
        {
            "ProductID": 5,
            "ProductName": "Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix",
            "SupplierID": 2,
            "CategoryID": 2,
            "QuantityPerUnit": "36 boxes",
            "UnitPrice": 21.35,
            "UnitsInStock": 0,
            "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
            "ReorderLevel": 0,
            "Discontinued": true,
            "Category": {
                "CategoryID": 2,
                "CategoryName": "Condiments",
                "Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
            },
            "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 7, 17)
        },
        {
            "ProductID": 6,
            "ProductName": "Grandma's Boysenberry Spread",
            "SupplierID": 3,
            "CategoryID": 2,
            "QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 8 oz jars",
            "UnitPrice": 25,
            "UnitsInStock": 120,
            "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
            "ReorderLevel": 25,
            "Discontinued": false,
            "Category": {
                "CategoryID": 2,
                "CategoryName": "Condiments",
                "Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
            },
            "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 9, 19)
        }]

    private gridData: GridDataResult = process(this.sampleProducts, this.state);

    protected dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
        this.state = state;
        this.gridData = process(this.sampleProducts, this.state);
    }


}
```

app.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { SecurityGroupService } from "./services/securityGroupService";
import { SecurityGroupComponent } from "./securityGroupComponent";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/';

import { test } from './test';

import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ButtonsModule,
        CommonModule,
        GridModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule        
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SecurityGroupComponent,
        test
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [SecurityGroupService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure the GridModule is imported in the same module where the "test" component is declared and used. For example, in the [Grid component installation instructions](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#toc-installation) there is only one module used - the AppModule, and both the AppComponent and the GridModule are imported there, and are also included in the "declarations" and "imports" arrays respectively.

Comment: Hi @topalkata, thanks for your response, in app.module everything is set up as you specified above. The grid does render and works until the filter attributes are added, that's when we see the error thrown. If there are other things you can think of that we can try pls let me know.

Comment: Hi @ranah, everything in the provided code seems correct. If you are using the latest (or recent) version of the Grid package, I could not think of other reasons for the described error (based on the provided code).

I put up a Plunkr that is working as expected, using the component and module code provided:


http://plnkr.co/edit/LyBOpYxmLEzqB7gBw2Ez?p=preview

If you share some similar example where the error can be observed, I would be glad to help determining what might be causing it.